How can I make the table cell width change with a variable
I want to change the width of the table cell dynamically. In a different file I define width do the calculation for it. Then I pass it to this templ function. Width is calculated by dividing i by total then multiplied by 100. In the styles section I want .done's width to change based on width.
templ contentComponent(Header string, body templ.Component, Image string, Next string, Previous string, Total int, i int, width int) {
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bar">
            <table style="width: 1000px; height: 25px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="done" style="width: {{ printf('%g%%', width) }};"> </td>
                    <td class="todo"> </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h1>{ Header }</h1>

        if Image == "No image" {
            <div class="default">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        }
        if Image != "No image" {
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src={ path.Base(Image) } ></img>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="content">
            @body
        </div> 
        <div class="next">
            if Previous != "" {
            <a href={ templ.SafeURL(Previous) } >Previous Page</a>
            }
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href='index.html'">Home</button>
            if Next != "" {
            <a href={ templ.SafeURL(Next) } >Next Page</a>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="PageNum">
            <span>{ fmt.Sprintf("%d of %d", i+1, Total) }</span> <!-- Display the page number -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style> 
    .bar table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders so they don't double up */
    }

    .bar td {
        border: 1px solid black; /* Add a solid black border to all table cells */
    }
    .done{
        width: { width }%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0);
    }
    .PageNum {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .default{
        width: 1px;
        height: 1px;
    }
    .container {
        position: relative; /* Make the container relatively positioned */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; /* Arrange children vertically */
        justify-content: flex-start; /* Align children at the start of the container */
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh; /* Set container height to at least viewport height */
        padding-top: 20px; /* Add padding to the top for spacing */
    }

    h1 {
        margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add some spacing below the header */
    }

    .image-container {
        margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add some spacing below the image */
    }

    .content {
        max-width: 600px; /* Optionally set a max width for the content */
        text-align: center; /* Center-align the content */
    }

    .image-container img {
        width: 150px; 
        height: 100px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Optional: Set a background color */
        margin: 0; /* Reset default margin */
    }
</style>
}

